# INSERT INTO queries to PSQL server does nothing

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have been trying to create a quick nodeJS application that allows me to quickly post some spreadsheet data into a PSQL database. I have never had any troubles with this before when I have previously used a PSQL database with a nodeJS application.

However, currently I am now having the trouble that when I do an `INSERT INTO` query I neither get an error, or any new data actually loaded into my database. I have used `console.log()` on the nodeJS side to reveal that the POST route is actually being called and it is receiving the correct data. I have also been able to reveal that the query it intends to send is correct (I have copied the queries the nodeJS app produces into pgAdmin to reveal that it is working as intended).

Yet, I get no error or any data in my database? I have a small snippet of my code directly relevant to the POST route below:

```
app.post('/', req => {
        var query = `INSERT INTO timeperception (timestamp, age, gender, hourssince, emotion, tempo, 
                hue, time_perception) VALUES (${req.body.timestamp}, ${req.body.age}, 
                '${req.body.gender}', ${req.body.hoursSince}, ${req.body.emotion}, 
                 ${req.body.tempo}, ${req.body.hue}, 12)`;
        console.log(query); // confirms to me that query is correct
        client.query(query, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err.message); // is meant to produce error if query fails
        });
    });
```

And here is some code for where I make my initial database connection:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING || process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
    sslmode: require
})
client.connect();
```

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: 1. You're not waiting for the client to connect. 2. The code is vulnerable to a trivial SQL injection attack and should not be used like this. See https://node-postgres.com/features/queries - the section on "Parameterized query".

Comment: Yeah I have made it up quickly and only I have access to the web app and the database so I didn't worry too much about protecting against injection attacks yet. I presume I need to use await/async to wait for the client to connect? I am unsure how to use these features properly and always run into some sort of error about everything having to be in an async function. Why haven't I had to consider the waiting for connection in previous examples, did they change something recently?

Comment: I'm not sure if node-postgres has an internal query buffer mechanism that holds queries back until connection time, but even if it does, there's always the possibility that your code is actually failing to connect in some way - you won't know till you check. Also, try logging something for the success scenario.

Comment: I see nothing that commits the transaction.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Do you mean you see nothing that does the `INSERT INTO` query? I believe the first block of code in my question should do it.

Comment: I mean that in order for the effects of transaction to persist a `COMMIT;` needs to be issued. Some clients do that with a default `AUTOCOMMIT` mode after every statement, otherwise the user/code needs to issue an explicit `COMMIT;` to persist the statement effects.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to use `Pool` instead of `Client` for my purpose of having a database connection that stayed constantly open to `INSERT INTO`'s at any moment. My code for the two blocks above had to change as follows to achieve this:

```
app.post('/', req => {
    var query = `...`; // place your actual query here instead of '...'
    pool.query(query, err => {
        if (err) console.log(err.message);
    });
});
```

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING || process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }, // this line is important for using Pool
    sslmode: require
})
client.connect();
```